# Struggling with calling lua functions from the command line

Tags: lua

I have the following code:

```lua
dofile(arg[1])

function1 = arg[2]
argument = arg[3]

returned = _G[function1](argument)
print(returned)
```

It is designed to take three command-line arguments and run a function from a file.

So, i run the command `lua libs.lua "printStuff.lua" "printStuff" "\"Hello, World\""`, and i always end up with this:

```
"Hello, World"
nil
```

I don't understand why i always get "nil".

Here are the contents of `printstuff.lua`:

```
function printStuff(stuff)
    print(stuff)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is to be expected. What's going on here:

1. You're executing the file specified by the first argument, `printstuff.lua`, which will leave a function `printStuff` in the global table `_G`.
2. You're indexing the global table with the second argument, `printStuff`, obtaining that function
3. You're calling the function you just obtained with the third command line argument, `"Hello World!"`, as parameter, which prints it, and storing the result of that in the global variable `returned`. The function `printStuff` **doesn't return anything (there's no `return` in there, and even if there was, `print` doesn't return anything either)**, so you're assigning `nil` to `returned`.
4. You're printing `returned`, which is `nil`

Side note: I'd use the vararg `...` instead of the `arg` table for improved readability:

```lua
local file, func, param = ...
dofile(file); print(func(param))
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. Now my code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply...

```
-- xlua.lua
-- Example: lua xlua.lua os date "%H:%M:%S"
-- Or: lua xlua.lua _G print "Hello World"
-- Or: lua xlua.lua dofile /path/to/someusefull.lua "Arg for someusefull.lua"

local result = _G[arg[1]][arg[2]](arg[3])

-- 5. Only put out whats not nil
if (result ~= nil) then
  print(result)
end
```